# Send a local file via Axios for debug purposes

Tags: javascript, axios

I am testing my application, and I want to send a local mp3 file that I have stored in my storage folder.

How can I send this via Axios? Should I convert it to a Blob/File, and if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

This code below is how I tried it, but it didn't work.

```
        const formData = new FormData();

        const file = new File('storage/app/audio/debug.mp3', 'test.mp3', {
            type: Blob,
            lastModified: Date.now()
        });

        formData.append('data', file);
        formData.append('id', urlId[2]);

        return Axios.post("http://voice-app.test/api/v1/file", formData, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("Bearer")}`,
            }
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.error(e); 
        })
```

Comment: The urlId[2] has no bearing on the question for what it's worth.